# Set PowerShell Aliases with a script

Tags: windows, powershell, alias

I created a PowerShell script to set aliases for a PowerShell session. When I run the script and try the alias, I get the error saying that the alias isn't recongized. How can I use the aliases that are set by the script?

Answer (score 7):

Run the script using [Dot sourcing operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6):

> `.` Dot sourcing operator 
>   Runs a script in the current scope so that any functions, **aliases**, and
>   variables that the script creates are added to the current scope.
>
> ```
> . c:\scripts\sample.ps1
> ```
>
> *Note*: The dot sourcing operator is followed by a space. Use the space
>   to distinguish the dot from the dot (`.`) symbol that represents the 
>   current directory. 
> In the following example, the `Sample.ps1` script
>   in the current  directory is run in the current scope.
>
> ```
> . .\sample.ps1
> ```

Comment: Is that using the absolute path, not a relative path?

Comment: The former example `. c:\scripts\sample.ps1` shows an absolute path while the latter example `. .\sample.ps1` shows a relative one.

Comment: `.` dot sourcing operator works dependently of environment